# Data not Saving in Database after Creating (CRUD)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, crud

I am working on simple CRUD application where I have two tables:

**Patient**

- CNIC (varchar 50 and PK)
- Name (varchar 50)

**PatientVaccines**

- Cnic (varchar 50 and FK)
- VaccinationName (varchar)
- VaccinationDate (varchar)
- CenterAddress   (varchar)

I know making string as PK, FK is not a good approach but this is my requirement.

I have a `PatientDBContext` class where I perform CRUD operations:

```
public class PatentDBContext
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;

    public List<Patient> getPatients()
    {
        List<Patient> PatientList = new List<Patient>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        string query = "SELECT p.CNIC, p.Name, pv.cnic, pv.VaccinationName, pv.VaccinationDate, pv.CenterAddress FROM Patient AS p JOIN PatientVaccines AS pv ON p.CNIC = pv.cnic";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Patient p = new Patient();
         
            p.CNIC = dr["CNIC"].ToString();
            p.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            p.VaccinationName = dr["VaccinationName"].ToString();
            //p.VaccinationDate = dr["VaccinationDate"].ToString();
            p.CentreAddress = dr["CenterAddress"].ToString();

            PatientList.Add(p);
        }

        con.Close();

        return PatientList;
    }

    public bool AddPatient(Patient pat)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddPatient", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", pat.CNIC);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", pat.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationName", pat.VaccinationName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationDate", pat.VaccinationDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CenterAddress", pat.CentreAddress);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool UpdatePatient(Patient pat)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        string query = "UPDATE PatientVaccines SET  VaccinationName = @VaccinationName, VaccinationDate = @VacinationDate, CenterAddress = @CenterAddress WHERE Cnic = @Cnic";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", pat.CNIC);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", pat.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationName", pat.VaccinationName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationDate", pat.VaccinationDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CenterAddress", pat.CentreAddress);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Errors is this class is in `getPatient()` function I comment it out `p.VaccinationDate` that shows an error that I cannot convert implicitly type string to DateTime, how do I convert it to DateTime?

I have another function names `AddPatient()`that now show any error or bug but when I click submit button after input records it doesn't perform any action.

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PatentDBContext db = new PatentDBContext();
        List<Patient> obj = db.getPatients();

        return View(obj);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Patient pat)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
            {
                PatentDBContext context = new PatentDBContext();
                bool check = context.AddPatient(pat);

                if (check == true)
                {
                    TempData["InsertMessage"] = "Data Inserted..";
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["FailureMessage"] = "Data Not Inserted";
                }

                ModelState.Clear();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(string Cnin)
    {
        PatentDBContext context = new PatentDBContext();

        //string str = Cnin.ToString();
        var row = context.getPatients().Find(model => model.CNIC = Cnin);
        return View(row);
    }
}
```

Here I also can't convert implicitly type string to bool

```
var row = context.getPatients().Find(model => model.CNIC = Cnin);
```

and finally this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddPatient]
    (@CNIC varchar(50),
     @Name varchar(50),
     @VaccinationName varchar(50),
     @VaccinationDate varchar(50),
     @CenterAddress varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Patient (CNIC, Name)
    VALUES (@CNIC, @Name)

    INSERT INTO PatientVaccines (Cnic, VaccinationName, VaccinationDate, CenterAddress)
    VALUES (@Cnic, @VaccinationName, @VaccinationDate, @CenterAddress)
END
```

Comment: **Do not, under any circumstances, save dates as strings.** That is one of the worst common mistakes on the book. **ALWAYS** use an appropriate data type - `Date` if you don't care about time, `DateTime2` if you don't care about time zone, or `DateTimeOffset` if you do.
Also, read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pretty sure that you are `very new` in this technology as there are some `basic mistake`. I am mentioning some `common mistake` below:

1. You **should not use** `varchar` as `primary key` instead use `int`
2. Make a relation in both parent and child table using `int` column.
3. Do not use `varchar` for `date field`, instead use `DateTime`.

I `redesigned` two tables as below:

**Patient Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CNIC] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Patient] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

> I introduce new column `Id` that set as [IDENTITY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5079/sql-server-identity-system-function-comparison/) so that this
> column will get value automatically like 1, 2, 3

**PatientVaccines Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PatientVaccines](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VaccinationName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [VaccinationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CenterAddress] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PatientId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PatientVaccines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

> I introduce two new columns `Id` and `PatientId`. when you insert a patient, the Id field will get a number automaticaly and that id will be inserted into `PatientVaccines Table` as `PatientId` so that you can find the relational data. Also I used `datetime` for `VaccinationDate`.

**FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PatientVaccines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PatientVaccines_Patient] FOREIGN KEY([PatientId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Patient] ([Id])
```

> This is a `constraint or rules` that will restrict you to insert data that is not relational. for example: you **do not** have a record of patient with Id `101` but you are trying to insert `PatientVaccines` record with `PatientId 101` then this rule will restrict you to do that.

**Here is the Sql Diagram of Two tables**

[image: Sql Diagram of Two tables]

By doing the above, you need to update your `Stored Procedure` as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddPatient]
    (@CNIC varchar(50),
     @Name varchar(50),
     @VaccinationName varchar(50),
     @VaccinationDate datetime,
     @CenterAddress varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Patient (CNIC, Name)
    VALUES (@CNIC, @Name)

    INSERT INTO PatientVaccines (PatientId, VaccinationName, VaccinationDate, CenterAddress)
    VALUES (@@Identity, @VaccinationName, @VaccinationDate, @CenterAddress)
END
```

Here is the complete `C#` Code where I made some correction

```
public class PatentDBContext
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;
    public List<Patient> getPatients()
    {
        List<Patient> PatientList = new List<Patient>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        string query = "SELECT p.CNIC, p.Name, pv.VaccinationName, pv.VaccinationDate, pv.CenterAddress FROM Patient AS p JOIN PatientVaccines AS pv ON p.Id = pv.PatientId";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Patient p = new Patient();
            p.CNIC = dr["CNIC"].ToString();
            p.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            p.VaccinationName = dr["VaccinationName"].ToString();
            p.VaccinationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["VaccinationDate"]);
            p.CenterAddress = dr["CenterAddress"].ToString();

            PatientList.Add(p);
        }

        con.Close();
        return PatientList;
    }

    public bool AddPatient(Patient pat)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddPatient", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", pat.CNIC);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", pat.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationName", pat.VaccinationName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationDate", pat.VaccinationDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CenterAddress", pat.CenterAddress);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool UpdatePatient(Patient pat)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        string query = "UPDATE PatientVaccines SET  VaccinationName = @VaccinationName, VaccinationDate = @VaccinationDate, CenterAddress = @CenterAddress WHERE PatientId = ( Select Id from Patient where Cnic = @Cnic)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", pat.CNIC);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", pat.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationName", pat.VaccinationName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VaccinationDate", pat.VaccinationDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CenterAddress", pat.CenterAddress);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1/3 There are a few things wrong with your answer, starting with the assumption that a surrogate key is enough to ensure data integrity. If you're going to add a surrogate key, you must use a unique constraint (or unique index) on the column that used to be the primary key, otherwise you might have duplicate data on different surrogate key values.>>>

Comment: 2/3 Next - in the second table you're using `DateTime`, which is not a critical mistake but you can do better by using `DateTime2`. Also, in the stored procedure, you didn't change the parameter type to match the type of the column, and the worst part - you're using `@@Identity`to get the newly inserted identity value, which is a mistake since `@@Identity` is database-wide range which means that it might give you the identity value created in an entirely different table (if it was inserted exactly between the insert and select statements). You should use `scope_identity()` in this case.>>>

Comment: 3/3 for more information read [Why You Should Never Use DATETIME Again!](https://susanibach.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/) by HockeyGeekGirl, and
[Use the right tool to get identity values back after an insert](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/use-the-right-tool-to-get-identity-values-back-after-an-insert/) by yours truly.

Comment: Sorry, by the time I've found the third link my last comment was too old to edit - so here it is:

[Does a table with a surrogate key require a unique constraint on a natural key to be in 1NF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840392/3094533)

Comment: And let's add the common - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). I would also argue that VaccinationDate should be DATE - no one generally cares about the exact time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your stored procedure is not correct, you can test it beforehand in the database.

```
// here you should use operator== instead of аssignment operator=
// Have in mind that .Find will throw an error if model with given Cnin is not found
var row = context.getPatients().Find(model => model.CNIC == Cnin);
```

[How to convert a string to datetime object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime)

[Create a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)

General advice, you can google the errors you get and find information about them